# How to write a java programme to find unique patterns by removing duplicates for API urls?

Tags: java, javascript, page-objects, excel, java-gui

How to write a java program to find unique patterns for API URLs?

Note: I have a file which contains 10000  API URLs with duplicates

**api.csv:**

```
http://abc.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=abtc&type=Products&ProductID=111&location=145
http://def.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=dewf&type=Products&ProductID=345&location=321
http://ghy.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=ghty&type=stores&ProductID=763
```

Unique patterns means removing duplicates like below:

```
[clientkey,type,ProductID,location]

[clientkey,type,ProductID]
```

For this:

```
http://abc.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=abtc&type=Products&ProductID=111&location=145
http://ghy.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=ghty&type=stores&ProductID=763
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what are you asking here, what are unique patterns ? why Java ?

Comment: What is your level of Java skills? Do you know how to do trivial task like write text to a file? If it is not obvious, you might need to work on your java, following some tutorials.

Comment: Unique patterns means i need to remove duplicates(i have a file which contains 10000 urls ).

Comment: Des it have to be java?  I can give you pseudocode easily enough.  Does performance matter?  If you have access to a unix system, look at "sort | uniq"

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean when say a "duplicate". What is the rule one shoould use to decide if there is a dup record they're looking at.

Comment: i have found a solution for this see below.

Comment: Guys, next thing is,  how to set sample values for below Out Put from the api.csv file. ex: [clientkey=abtc&type=Products&ProductID=111&location=145] and [clientkey=ghty&type=stores&ProductID=763] ???

Comment: not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer working fine for me**

```
public class LineMatcher {
    static Set<String> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void findBadLines(String aFileName) {
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        try
                (
                        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, ENCODING);
                        LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
                ) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.concat("&");
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=[^&]*&");
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    String str = m.group();
                    String cc = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
                    if (cc.isEmpty()) break;
                    line = line.replace(cc, "");
                    line = line.replace("=&", "+");
                    m = pattern.matcher(line);
                }
                linkedHashSet.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 public static void main(String... arguments) {

LineMatcher lineMatcher = new LineMatcher();
lineMatcher.findBadLines("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New folder\\api.csv"); 

for (String i : linkedHashSet) 
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

}

Out Put(removing duplicates):

http://abc.com/XMLFeed?clientkey+type+ProductID+location+

http://ghy.com/XMLFeed?clientkey+type+ProductID+